# How to get height and width from base64 encoded image?

Tags: php, base64

I need to get the height and width from an base64 encoded image.

According to other sites `getimagesizefromstring()` should do the trick, but for me it doesn't work at all.

Example code:

```
    <?php
    $image = "data:image;base64,/9j/4AAQdihdiwd......";
    $data = getimagesizefromstring($image);
    echo $data[0]; // no output
    print_r($data); // no output
```

What I did wrong?

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php shows what?

Comment: You have to convert it back to an image from the base64 string that it is currently

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You passed to the [getimagesizefromstring function](http://php.net/getimagesizefromstring) a [data URI string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) which is used to display an image in HTML, while the binary representation of the image is expected.

You need to grab the base64 encoded string first then decode it:

```
<?php
$image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQdihdiwd......';
$binary = \base64_decode(\explode(',', $image)[1]);

$data = \getimagesizefromstring($binary);
print_r($data);
```

Comment: Great! Works like a charm. Thanks

Comment: Handle unexpected situations as well. There may be no `,` symbol if the string is malformed, value may not encode properly etc. You can play with the value of `$image` by yourself to check if your script is error prone.

Comment: There are several similar questions and all answers say to use `getimagesizefromstring()` but according to the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) it only works on JFIF (JPEG) image types. Is there a way to do this for any PNG/GIF/JPEG image?

Comment: ACK -nevermind it is only the optional parameter `imageinfo` that is limited to JFIF image types.